# ASP.NET :URL masking

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have an ASP.NET web application where i have a page Signup.aspx and a home page.aspx.In my home page i have link to the signup.aspx page.I want to Hide the file extension.aspx from the addressbar when someone clicks on the signup link in home page.I want to show it as http://mysite.com/signup  . Is there anyway to do this ? I am using VS 2008

thanks in advance

Comment: What version of IIS will this be running on? It does affect the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET 3.5 ASP.NET Routing could be a good choice for you.

MSDN page: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Using it with ASP.NET MVC at ScottGu blog: [weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Using it with ASP.NET 3.5: [www.techbubbles.com/aspnet/aspnet-35-url-routing/](http://www.techbubbles.com/aspnet/aspnet-35-url-routing/)

If your website runs under ASP.NET 2.0 Helicon ISAPI Rewrite could be a good choise for you. This is an IIS filter that redirects requests to your pages according to regex-based configuration file. They have a free version for one website.

Have a look at Helicon: [www.isapirewrite.com](http://www.isapirewrite.com)

Comment: Oh when exactly did I answer this question? Almost 4 years, wow :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would just be having a folder named "signup" with a default page that redirects to signup.aspx

Comment: Hew ... can you imagine how would this look like for a web site with hundreds of pages!?

Comment: He didn't say he had hundreds of pages, it was an answer to his very specific question.

(Keep it simple stupid:)

Answer (score 0):

Another option which does not involve rewriting the URL yourself is using the [ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) which will handle that kind of stuff pretty easily.

Comment: But my hosting provider does not support IIS 7 .Its IIS 6 .I cant to any isap tricks too ,Its ixWEbHosting

Comment: simply linking to the main page of a framework is not helpful. No specific answer is given here.